# Check SSO using WIF-ADFS

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, wif, adfs

I am developing a website using WIF-ADFS technology to achieve single sign on (SSO).
As such, the page will first automatically redirected to the ADFS Page, however the users will then need to input their ADFS Login Credential.
If ADFS-Login is successful, the page will then redirect back to my site with the claims.

The questions are:

1. Can I omit the ADFS-Login step? regardless of my device and my working network?
2. If yes, what response should I expect if the user is not recognized by ADFS? will there be no claims sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not omit the ADFS login step.
If everything is configured correctly in ADFS, IE and Chrome will likely do automatic logon. Firefox won't, Mobile devices won't and Linux machines won't also.

If a user is not authenticated ADFS will never send him back to your application. If a user accesses your application without being authenticated, he will be redirected (or the access will be denied).

Comment: can I ask additional question? whether it is possible for the user to first choose if he/she want to use the SSO functionality or not (no redirect to ADFS page).

Comment: I'm not sure about the SO rules about that, but I'd answer ;)